# Call to a member function prepare() on null - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have searched every single answer regarding this and none seem to fully answer what's going on.
Currently I am getting the error in the title when trying to prepare a statement with pdo.

I have tried:

Using a constructor instead

Using non-static

Using $this when I had a constructor

Catching PDO exceptions, none seem to be thrown

Here is main.php

```
class db {
    public static $db;
    public static $db2;

    public static function start() {
        $host = "localhost";
        $dbname = "dbname";
        $usr = "user";
        $ps = "pass";

        $pdo = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
        $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
        ];
        try {
        db::$db = new PDO($pdo, $usr, $ps, $opt);

        return db::$db;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And then to initialize the database, I call the start function in index.php with `db::start();`

Now, to the error.

Within main.php, in a whole different class and function, I try to call this connection statically.

```
$stmt0 = db::$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname=:u");
```

But when done, I receive the error in the title, on this line.

Most would probably think, hmm, there must be an error with the connection then if it is calling it null. If that's the case, something is preventing my exception from being thrown because I see nothing in the error logs or on the page.

Comment: you does not echo error if try block fails $e->getMessage();

Comment: add echo and you will see the error

Comment: it echo's nothing, and I've tried error_log as well.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili because there is no error to show, he's calling `prepare` on the static propety `$db`, which of course it's null in this context because `$db` is never set to a value and defaults to null. The code should be `$stmt = db::start()->prepare()`

Comment: @Andrew he said he's calling db:start() first so no problem should be with db:$db

Comment: @Machavity you see the config? PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,

Answer (score 1):

Your PDO is failing to connect, and since you aren't doing anything with that condition (you `catch` it but then silently drop it), it's going under the radar.

Try removing the `try..catch` block. If an error is happening in connection, you need to know!

Comment: Removed the `try..catch` block, still getting the prepare on null error

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code on http://phpfiddle.org/ and it works:
(open URL, swtich to "CodeSpace" and paste the code below)

```
<?php

class db {
    public static $db;
    public static function start() {
        $opt = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
        ];
        try {
            require "util/public_db_info.php";
            $db = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);
            return $db;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

$db = db::start();

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE id <= 10");
$status = $result->execute();

if (($status) && ($result->rowCount() > 0))
{
    $results = array();

    //convert query result into an associative array
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    var_dump($results);

}


?>
```